# Livewire The server returned a "405 Method Not Allowed". in production and not problem in develop stage

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I've working with app made with TALL. On local work fine, and on production one page with 3 forms, get error  "405 Method Not Allowed"

Error trace show a problem on POST method instead GET method.

The form is a mix of three forms.
1- The one with the profile
2. The one with the password
3. The one with the token

All three forms are components of livewire.

Each one has their buton, to save.

Thus, the error occurs in any of the three save buttons, in production.

### wep.php

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'as' => 'admin.', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
   ...
   Route::get('/profile', Profile::class)->name('profile');
   ... 
}
```

### Profile.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class Profile extends Component
{

    public User $user;

    public function mount() { $this->user = auth()->user(); }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.profile');
    }
}
```

### UpdatePassword.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Profile;

use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\User;

class UpdatePassword extends Component
{
    //public User $user;

    public $password;
    public $password_confirmation;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.profile.update-password');
    }

    protected $rules = [
            'password' => [
                'required',
                'confirmed',
                'min:10',
                'regex:/^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\x])(?=.*[!$#%]).*$/',
            ],
    ];

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();

        auth()->user()->update([
            'password' => bcrypt($this->password)
        ]);

        $this->emitSelf('notify-saved');

        $this->resetForm();
    }

    protected function resetForm()
    {
        $this->password = '';
        $this->password_confirmation = '';
    }

}
```

### UpdateProfile.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Profile;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class UpdateProfile extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public User $user;

    public $upload;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.profile.update-profile');
    }

    protected function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'user.name' => [
                'string',
                'required',
                'min:5',
            ],
            'user.email' => [
                'email:rfc',
                'required',
                'regex:/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix',
                'unique:users,email,' . $this->user->id,
            ],
            'upload' => [
                'nullable',
                'image',
                'mimes:jpg,bmp,png',
                'max:200'
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function mount() { $this->user = auth()->user(); }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $this->user->save();

        $this->upload && $this->user->update([
            'avatar' => $this->upload->store('/', 'avatars'),
        ]);

        $this->emitSelf('notify-saved');
    }

}
```

### UpdateToken.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Auth\Profile;

use App\Helpers\ApiHelpers;
use Livewire\Component;

class UpdateToken extends Component
{
    public string $token;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->resetState();
    }

    public function updateToken()
    {

        $user = auth()->user();

        ApiHelpers::deleteTokenUserType($user->id, 'auth_token');

        $this->token = auth()->user()->createToken('auth_token')->plainTextToken;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.auth.profile.update-token');
    }

    protected function resetState()
    {
        $this->token = '';
    }
}
```

### profile.blade.php

```php
<div>
    @livewire('auth.profile.update-profile')
    <!-- Contraseña -->
    <div class="hidden sm:block" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="py-5">
            <div class="border-t border-gray-200"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @livewire('auth.profile.update-password')

    <!-- Token -->
    <div class="hidden sm:block" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="py-5">
            <div class="border-t border-gray-200"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @livewire('auth.profile.update-token')
</div>
```

### update-profile.blade.php

```php
<div>
    <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6 border-gray-300">
        <div class="md:col-span-1">
            <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Perfil</h3>
            <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                Esta información es privada y sólo tiene efectos administrativos.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
                <div class="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
                    <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-6 sm:p-6">
                        <!-- Nombre -->
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                            <div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                                <label for="name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                    Nombre
                                </label>
                                <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    <input wire:model.defer="user.name" type="text" name="username" id="username" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 flex-1 block w-full rounded-none rounded-r-md sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    @error('user.name')
                                    <div class="mt-1 text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                            <div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                                <label for="email" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                    Email
                                </label>
                                <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    <input wire:model.defer="user.email" type="text" name="email" id="email" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 flex-1 block w-full rounded-none rounded-r-md sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    @error('user.email')
                                    <div class="mt-1 text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div>
                            <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                Foto
                            </label>
                            <div class="mt-1 flex items-center space-x-5">
                                    <span class="inline-block h-12 w-12 rounded-full overflow-hidden bg-gray-100">
                                        @if ($upload)
                                            <img src="{{ $upload->temporaryUrl() }}" alt="Profile Photo">
                                        @else
                                            <img src="{{ auth()->user()->avatarUrl() }}" alt="Profile Photo">
                                        @endif
                                    </span>
                                <input type="file" wire:model="upload" id="photo">
                                <div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    @error('user.avatar')
                                    <div class="mt-1 text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                            Save
                        </button>
                        <span x-data="{ open: false }"
                              x-init="@this.on('notify-saved',
                                    () => {
                                        if (open === false) setTimeout(() => { open = false }, 3500);
                                        open = true;
                                    })"
                              x-show.transition.out.duration.1000ms="open"
                              style="display: none;"
                              class="text-gray-500">¡Guardado!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### update-password.blade.php

```php
<div>
    <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6 border-gray-300">
        <div class="md:col-span-1">
            <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Contraseña</h3>
            <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                Puede cambiar su contraseña en este formulario
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="save">
                <div class="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
                    <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-6 sm:p-6">

                        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                            <div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                                <label for="password" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                    Contraseña
                                </label>
                                <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    <input wire:model.defer="password" type="password" name="password" id="password" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 flex-1 block w-full rounded-none rounded-r-md sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="Nueva contraseña">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    @error('password')
                                    <div class="mt-1 text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                            <div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                                <label for="password_confirmation" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                    Confirma la contraseña
                                </label>
                                <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    <input wire:model.defer="password_confirmation" type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password_confirmation" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 flex-1 block w-full rounded-none rounded-r-md sm:text-sm border-gray-300">
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt-1 relative rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    @error('password_confirmation')
                                    <div class="mt-1 text-red-500 text-sm">{{ $message }}</div>
                                    @enderror
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                            Cambiar
                        </button>
                        <span x-data="{ open: false }"
                              x-init="@this.on('notify-saved',
                                    () => {
                                        if (open === false) setTimeout(() => { open = false }, 3500);
                                        open = true;
                                    })"
                              x-show.transition.out.duration.1000ms="open"
                              style="display: none;"
                              class="text-gray-500">¡Contraseña cambiada!
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### update-token.php

```php
<div>
    <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6 border-gray-300">
        <div class="md:col-span-1">
            <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Token API</h3>
            <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-500">
                El token solo se muestra una vez generado, por seguridad.
                <br />Copielo y guardelo en un lugar seguro.
                <br />El anterior se elimina del sistema, dejan de ser operativo.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="updateToken">
                <div class="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
                    <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-6 sm:p-6">
                        <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-6">
                            <div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                                <label for="token" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                                    Token
                                </label>
                                <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    <input wire:model="token" type="text" name="token" id="token"  disabled class="disabled:opacity-50 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 flex-1 block w-full rounded-none rounded-r-md sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="Haz click en el botón para regenerar el token">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                            Regenerar
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you just starting a project, or is there similar code that works?

Comment: Is project that work in local but has a issue in one form, in production @gnasher729

Answer (score 0):

An unforgivable mistake.

As a system administrator, I have forgotten, that you have to review the logs. And among others the mod_security log.

```
--9ac02665-F--
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
allow: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
date: Fri, 12 Nov 2021 15:18:31 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Server: Apache

--9ac02665-H--
Message: Warning. Matched phrase ".profile" at REQUEST_FILENAME. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec_vendor_configs/OWASP3/rules/REQUEST-930-APPLICATION-ATTACK-LFI.conf"] [line "124"] [id "930130"] [msg "Restricted File Access Attempt"] [data "Matched Data: .profile found within REQUEST_FILENAME: /livewire/message/auth.profile.update-profile"] [severity "CRITICAL"] [ver "OWASP_CRS/3.3.2"] [tag "application-multi"] [tag "language-multi"] [tag "platform-multi"] [tag "attack-lfi"] [tag "paranoia-level/1"] [tag "OWASP_CRS"] [tag "capec/1000/255/153/126"] [tag "PCI/6.5.4"]
```